# OpenCV line detection in general

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I am new to opencv (in c++) and I am trying to implement line detection.

I have a picture with a couple of lines and I am trying to determine the distance between the lines. I know there is Hough, Canny and so on but how can I get the coordinates of the different lines to calculate the distance between the lines? Should I use opencv contour functions or are there better ways? I do not need complete code samples, but can anyone tell me the best way to get the job done?

Comment: You don't need to add signature to your post - your user card is added automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Line detections lead often to using Hough transform, Canny edge detector and contour detection only act as convenient pre-processors if needed.

If you have **parallel lines**, use

```
void HoughLines(InputArray image, OutputArray lines, double rho, double theta, int threshold, double srn=0, double stn=0 )
```

for detecting lines where the second parameter will contain the detection:

> lines – Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a
>   two-element vector (ρ, θ) . ρ is the distance from the coordinate
>   origin (0, 0) (top-left corner of the image). θ is the line rotation
>   angle in radians ( 0 ∼ vertical line, π/2 ∼ horizontal line ).
>   [opencv2refman.pdf]

This means, that the distance between two lines should be `abs(rho1-rho2)`, that the distances are absolute differences between pixel values in the first column of `lines`. (Note: method should be `CV_HOUGH_STANDARD` here!)

For **non-parallel lines** you have to define what you think of as a distance, but then OpenCV may still provide you with the coordinates of endpoints of each detected line.
You just have to use `method = CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC`.

> CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC probabilistic Hough transform (more efficient
>   in case if the picture contains a few long linear segments). It
>   returns line segments rather than the whole line. Each segment is
>   represented by starting and ending points, and the matrix must be (the
>   created sequence will be) of the CV_32SC4 type.
>   [opencv2refman.pdf]

You can also find a tutorial in `opencv_tutorials.pdf` within the documentation of your installed OpenCV.

Comment: thank you for your answer! In the next step I want to get an estimate of the quality of the lines in my picture. the lines are edges of grooving and should be parallel. At several places the grooving is demaged and the edges aren't parallel anymore. Is there an easy way to get the deviation of an actual edge from a straight line?

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure. I think it is worth posting it as a separate question.